# How to add a prop to an object depending on a conditional statement

Tags: javascript

I have a obj that I want to add a property to depending on a condition as below:

```
 someFunc(a, b) {
    const test = {
      a: a,
      b: b,
      isTest: true,
      update: true // I want to add this field only if the condition is true otherwise don't add at all.          
    };
  }
```

I tried doing:

```
isFieldReq ? {update: true} : {}
```

but this does not work at all! it adds another empty object.
Any ideas?

Comment: Awesome, Thank you all for the prompt answers..works like charm!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because test is `const` doesn't mean it's not alterable. It just means it cannot be reassigned.

As such,

```
delete test['update'];
```

will remove the update field. Apply this conditionally, and you should be good. Conversely, you could also set update later i.e

```
const test = {
  a: a,
  b: b,
  isTest: true,
};
if(isFieldReq) test['update'] = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put

```
someFunc(a, b) {
    const test = {
      a: a,
      b: b,
      isTest: true    
    };
    //pay attention here
    if(isFieldReq){
      test.update = true
    }
  }
```

Comment: This should be `test.update = true` with an equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like the following to add the property.

```
someFunc(a, b) {
  const test = {
    a: a,
    b: b,
    isTest: true
  }

  // Conditional below to add property to test
  if (test.isTest) {
    test['update'] = true
  }

  return test
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass plain object to first parameter to `Object.assign()`, pass conditional operator as second parameter.

```js
let isFieldReq = true;

const o = {
  someFunc(a, b) {
    const test = Object.assign({a, b, isTest: true}
                 , isFieldReq ? {update: true} : {});
    return test
  }
}

console.log(o.someFunc(1, 2));

isFieldReq = false;

console.log(o.someFunc(3, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign`, taking advantage of the fact that it skips falsy arguments.

```
someFunc(a, b) {
  const test = Object.assign(
    {a, b, isTest: true}, 
    condition && {update: true}
  );
  console.log(test);
}
```